# Variable that stores filename it is in

Tags: linux, bash, variables

Is there a way to store a filename in a variable where the variable argument is written? Instead of hardcoding the filename, i would want the variable to know which file its in and store the name of the file in a variable.

Comment: In `bash`, `$0` gives the name of the shell or shell script that is running, if that helps.

Comment: Seems to be what I need but it displays filename the same way it was called; relative or absolute. How would this behave in cron?

Comment: @Andy why not try and find out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dirname $0  will give the directory relative to how it was called, so you need to get the expanded path like this:

```
FULLPATH=$( cd $(dirname $0); pwd)
```

basename $0 will give the shell script name so

```
SHORTNAME=$(basename $0)

$FULLPATH/$SHORTNAME  # is the fully qualified location of the current script.
```

The full path name is discussed as the most frequent bash question: 
[Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within)